# disable two discounts in magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I created a Shopping Rule condition wherein my customers with products worth more than $50 in their cart is given 10% discount automatically.

Now, if the same user have a coupon code for 10% and he applies it, gets another 10% discount. This is a strict No.

I'm testing magento and wondering if anyone has a solution to add a condition to check the discounts be applied only once and not twice?

Comment: Try this. While creating a new rule in the actions tab, set "Stop further rule processing" dropdown to "Yes". Set this for both your rules ie, 10% for orders above $50 and also to the 10% discount coupon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Magento default provide this type of functionality` just check image

[image]

Let me know if you have any query